# The actionperformed don't get the signals from jbutton

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, action, jbutton

I'm trying to make a code to move an oval so I set the oval inside a transparent JPanel (its going to be a red JPanel on a red background) and using actionperformed to move the JPanel. After I will make the JButton work I intend to add keybinders. why don't the actionperformed method get the signals from the JBUtton?

```
public class PanelExample_Extended{

public static final int OVAL_WIDTH = 20, OVAL_HEIGHT = 20;
public static int x1 = 50, y1 = 100;
JButton upButton;
JPanel transparentPanel;

public class MyGraphics extends JComponent {



    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7526472295622776147L;

    MyGraphics() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(20,20));
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponents(g);
        g.setColor(Color.blue);
        g.fillOval(0, 0, OVAL_WIDTH, OVAL_HEIGHT);
    }

}

 public JPanel createContentPane (){

    JPanel totalGUI = new JPanel();
    totalGUI.setLayout(null);

    transparentPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    transparentPanel.setBackground(Color.red);
    transparentPanel.setLocation(x1, y1);
    transparentPanel.setSize(20,20);
    MyGraphics tr = new MyGraphics();
    tr.setLocation(0, 0);
    transparentPanel.add(tr);
    totalGUI.add(transparentPanel);

    upButton = new JButton("up");
    upButton.setLocation(0,50);
    upButton.setSize(50,50);
    totalGUI.add(upButton);


    totalGUI.setOpaque(true);
    return totalGUI;
}

private static void createAndShowGUI() {

    JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("[=] ??? [=]");


    PanelExample_Extended demo = new PanelExample_Extended();
    frame.setContentPane(demo.createContentPane());

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(290, 100);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public void ActionPerformed(ActionEvent h){
    if( h.getSource() == upButton) {
        y1 = y1  - 10;
        transparentPanel.setLocation(x1, y1);
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            createAndShowGUI();
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: Can you slim down your code so that it only includes a `JButton` implementation?

Comment: This code is slimmed from a much bigger one and I tried to make it so it would include only the minimum components for the qustion to be relevant...

Comment: but i get your point. I'll edit it.

Comment: @עמוסרום, do you even take the time to read comments? On you last posting (http://stackoverflow.com/q/19575849/131872) I stated you should NOT be using static variables. Why do you post questions when you don't listen to the suggestions??? We give you suggestions to avoid current and future problems.

Comment: @camickr: ah, x1, and y1, I see them now. Yep they should not be static.

Comment: yes I did read it and if you'd compare the codes, you'll see that the x1 and y1 are not anymore controlling directly the oval but the jpanel, because th JPanel is supposed to move I figured out they should be static...

Comment: Well if you read my comment in the other class I specifically mentioned the X1, Y1. But in addition the width/height should not be static because they are properties of the component which determines the size of oval. It would be a terrible design to force all instances of this class to be the same size.

Comment: @עמוסרום: no, they should not be static. If you are required to make them static, then you are using them wrong.

Comment: That is not what static is used for. static means that all instance of this class will use the same value. What if you requirement changes so that you need to use two components at two different locations on the panel and each component has a different size?

Comment: guys, I'm really listening to all of your comments and answers and I'm trying to learn every thing and google every question before I post it (and by so, solving 99.99% of my problems). That's my first swing code and I'm having a hard time with it. Thank you all a lot for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no call to `addActionListener(...)` anywhere. No button will work unless you first "hook it up" with a listener, and that is your responsibility as the coder.

Solution: call `addActionListener(...)` on your JButton and pass in the appropriate listener. This is all well described in the [JButton tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) (link now added), and if you are serious about learning Swing, I suggest you not only look at it, but study it.

---

Edit:

- Also your code has no ActionListener either! You really should read the tutorial at the link I've provided.
- And as @Radiodef points out, you have capitalized actionPerformed wrong. Be sure to precede all overridden methods with the `@Override` annotation to have the compiler check that you are doing it correctly, that your method "signature" is right.
- Also, as camickr points out, x1 and y1 should not be static. You should give the class that holds them public setter methods, `setX1(int x1)` and `setY1(int y1)` and have classes that need to set these fields call these methods.
- Also, when moving components, be sure to call `revalidate()` and `repaint()` on the container that holds them so that they are repositioned and redrawn.

Comment: Actually, I did study it from http://www.macs.hw.ac.uk/guidebook/?name=JButton&page=2 which I fount easier to read. I missed this part but even when I implement the action listener and add the line       upButton.addActionListener(this);
it doesn't move...

Comment: `ActionPerformed` also needs to be changed to `actionPerformed`.

Comment: guys, I'm really listening to all of your comments and answers and I'm trying to learn every thing and google every question before I post it (and by so, solving 99.99% of my problems). That's my first swing code and I'm having a hard time with it. Thank you all a lot for your help!